# is there a way to optimise this simple multiplication algorithm?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization

while doing a local coding contest i found a problem that was simple yet difficult to optimize, the problem was as follows: "given an array of `[1, 2, 3]`, find i-th number using this formula: `arr[i] = arr[i - 3] + arr[i - 2] * arr[i - 1]`, and type the value of `arr[249] % 169` into the answer box."

it wasn't too difficult, but since the formula used the last 3 numbers in the array, that means that the it was VERY exponential, the difference between arr[8] and arr[9] was in the trillions, and it gets way bigger way faster.

the problem in the contest was seemingly asking for a lot, but i do have some suspicion that the modulus part of it could've heavily simplified the process. how? i really don't know.

i tried both a simple recursive function and a for loop in python (i am not experienced with any other language, so i cant try this in a faster one), neither of those approaches could brute force this problem in an acceptable amount of time, i didn't try to exploit the modulus part because i don't know how i can achieve that, nor am i sure if it is even possible.

here are my solutions, in function form:

```py
def recursion(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return n
    
    return recursion(n - 3) + recursion(n - 2) * recursion(n - 1)
 
def forLoop(n):
    arr = []
    for i in range(n):
        if len(arr) < 3:
            arr.append(i + 1)
            continue
        
        arr.append(arr[0] + arr[1] * arr[2])
        arr.pop(0)
    
    return arr[2]
 
 
testNum = 6
r = recursion(testNum)
f = forLoop(testNum)
 
print(r, f)
```

Comment: Move your code from pastebin to verbatim code blocks in your question.

Comment: @Reinderien i tried but i didn't figure out how, the editing of the question was different then the writing of the question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your approach:

1. The problem can be solved in linear time, instead of recursion, using a simple for loop.
2. We can use the Modulo Arithmetic rules to keep the numbers always in `[0, 169)`.

## Solving the first problem

We can use the memoization here. Suppose that we want to find `arr[100]`. What information do we need to find this?

We have the formula: `arr[i] = arr[i - 3] + arr[i - 2] * arr[i - 1]`

Therefore, we will have `arr[100] = arr[97] + arr[98] * arr[99]`.

Think about the following scenario: We have `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[2]`. What if we compute and store `arr[3]`? What if after storing `arr[3]`, we compute `arr[4]`? ...? What if after storing `arr[99]`, we compute `arr[100]`?

We can easily see that `arr[100]` can be computed in constant time, as we already have `arr[97]`, `arr[98]` and `arr[99]` stored with us.

You can see another example of this approach here: [nth Fibonacci number in linear time](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/fibonacci-numbers.html#fibonacci-in-linear-time).

## Solving the second problem

Coming to second problem, the problem can be solved using the rules of Modulo Arithmetic. Here are the rules that we need:

```
(a + b) % n = ((a % n) + (b % n)) % n
(a * b) % n = ((a % n) * (b % n)) % n
```

Since we only require `arr[249] % 169`, we can assume `n=169` and our problem is reduced to finding `arr[i] % n` for all `i` from `0` to `249`. Thus, we can convert our equation into this:

```
Let b[i] = arr[i] % n. We need b[249].

b[i]
= arr[i] % n
= (arr[i - 3] + arr[i - 2] * arr[i - 1]) % n
= ((arr[i - 3] % n) + (arr[i - 2] * arr[i - 1]) % n) % n
= (b[i - 3] + ((arr[i - 2] % n) * (arr[i - 1] % n)) % n) % n
= (b[i - 3] + (b[i - 2] * b[i - 1]) % n) % n.
```

Therefore, instead of returning `arr[249] % 169`, we simply return `b[249]`.

## Pseudo code

Here is the pseudo code for the same:

```
mod = 169
b = [0,0,0,...] # Size of b is 250
b[0] = 1
b[1] = 2
b[2] = 3

for i = 3 to 249 (included):
    b[i] = (b[i - 3] + (b[i - 2] * b[i - 1]) % mod) % mod

print b[249]
```

This should make everything clear.